How to make a RegExp that matches any beginning part of the RegExp?
I am looking for an expression that matches ^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$ and any string that matches any beginning of this expression.
So basically...
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{1}$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}:$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{1}$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - $/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} -$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} $/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{1}$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}:$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{2}$/ ||
      /^[0-9]{1}$/

...Which is what i am using right now. But i would like to make it shorter.
/^[0-9]{0,2}:?[0-9]{0,2} ?-? ?[0-9]{0,2}:?[0-9]{0,2}$/ doesnt work for me, since it also matches for example "22: - 23:00".
It is possible?

You might also want to specify which environment you run the regex in as some might provide an easy way to get partial matches

An idea I've not used yet: Instead of making a long complicated pattern, why not... 1.) make a variable format with a valid string 00:00 - 00:00 2.) use a simple pattern like ^\d{2}:\d{2} - \d{2}:\d{2}$ 3.) fill up str to validate with format and check pattern. See this JS demo at tio.run

Please provide examples of input that should match and example that should not match.

I expect what you are looking for is the following, which I've written in extended, or free-spacing, mode (/x), to make it easier to both write and read.
^\d
  (?:\d
    (?::
      (?:\d
        (?:\d
          (?:\s
            (?:-
              (?:\s
                (?:\d
                  (?:\d
                    (?::
                      (?:\d{1,2}
                      )?
                    )?
                  )?
                )?
              )?
            )?
          )?
        )?
      )?
    )?
  )?$

In extended mode all whitespace is stripped in a pre-processing step, except when the whitespace is escaped (\s, \ ), is within a character class ([ ]) or is so specified by a Unicode token ([[:space:]], \p{Space}).
The question mark at the end of each
(?:...                     ...)?

makes the non-capture group optional.
Demo

We don't know yet what environment you're using but the following idea can be easily adapted to most languages. For showcase I use a Javascript snippet.
Instead of writing a long pattern that covers each case, you could use a simple pattern and fill up the test-string with a predefined format that matches the pattern.
See this vanilla JS demo at tio.run or try the following snippet.


$("#checkStr").on("keyup", function()
{
  // any valid string
  const format = '00:00 - 00:00';
    
  // simple pattern
  const p = /^\d\d:\d\d - \d\d:\d\d$/;
  
  // fill up with format and test
  let valid =  p.test(this.value+format.substring(this.value.length));
  
  // demo showcase
  if(!valid) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#eea39c';
    this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.length-1);
  } setTimeout(() => { this.style.backgroundColor = '#88dd85'; }, 700);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js">
</script><input id="checkStr" style="font-size: 20px" type="text" value="">



